# javascript. How to forbide object properties creation

Tags: javascript

I need a way to avoid create custom properties for an object.
This is my code:

```
object_to_instance = function () {
  this["elem1"] = 0;
  this["elem2"] = 0;
  // ....
  this["elem_n"] = 0;
}

my_obj = new object_to_instance();
my_obj.elem1 =7;
```

**What I want is a way to avoid that :**

```
my_obj.ele2 = 8 // (The m of elem2 is missing)
```

could be possible.

Now I have a ele2 property but I'd want an error!

Also, using `strict mode` does not help.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can seal and/or freeze an object if you are using ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Object.seal(yourObject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions):

> The `Object.preventExtensions()` method prevents new properties from ever being added to an object (i.e. prevents future extensions to the object).

Simply call `Object.preventExtensions(my_obj)` whenever you want to lock the properties.

Unlike `Object.seal`, this will still allow existing properties to be deleted.

Note that this will [only work in modern browers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.preventExtensions); in particular, IE 8 and below do not support it.

Comment: As far as I understand, `Object.seal` allows you to modify existing properties as well, but it doesn't allow to *delete* them. Easy to find out though.

Comment: @FelixKling Whoops, I forgot the difference between `[[Writable]]` (which is true for sealed properties) and `[[Configurable]]` (which is false) -- you are correct.